# Is it possible to catch like event from the Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying not to ask a dumb question that will get down voted but I really can't seem to find a yes / no for what I am looking for.

I just want to know if I can hook into the ***like*** event on the **Facebook page**. I have seen plenty of examples of doing so if YOU have the button on your site etc. but nothing I have come across so far tells me / shows me how to catch the event on the fb page.

I have read plenty about custom tabs and have made notes about several tabs I want to add but nothing about customizing / working with the main page.

The idea is not so much fan-gating as much as prompting them if they would like more information.

Hey you liked this you may be interested in....that sorta thing.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

here you go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

- **edge.create** - fired when the user likes something (fb:like).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not making the connection. Where / how do I "set" such a hook on the facebook page? Do you create an app on facebook? I thought that was just for having an app on your page but if it can interact with the facebook api vi javascript then that would be the piece of information I am missing.

Comment: any interactions are made in the context of the app. So yes, you must create one. Then you have your fan page which loads some content. On that page you need to add FB JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ - and then you should be able to track the events.